# Getting wrong values from a vector of structs in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, vector, struct

It have been years since i last programmed with vectors and other structures (most of them in college) and now I'm having a problem that i can't identify for sure most for this knowledge gap.

So, here's the part of the code I think it's with problems:

```
if (pos == -1) {
    cout<< "New Neighbor\n";
    neighborRecord newRec; //declaring newRec as type struct neighborRecord

    newRec.id = nodeID; //receiving values
    newRec.x = x_ngb;
    newRec.y = y_ngb;
    newRec.z = z_ngb;
    newRec.x_dst = x_dst; //L
    newRec.y_dst = y_dst;
    newRec.z_dst = z_dst;
    newRec.ts = simTime().dbl();
    newRec.timesRx = 1;
    newRec.ic = IC;
    cout<< "NEW REC IC" << newRec.ic<<"\n"; //until here i checked and it's all ok with variables

    neighborTable.push_back(newRec);
```

But then when I make a loop for reading the vector, I get wrong values.
Here's the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < neighborTable.size(); i++){

   trace()<< "ID: "<< neighborTable[i].id <<"\n";
   trace()<< "X : "<< neighborTable[i].x<<"\n";
   trace()<< "Y : "<< neighborTable[i].y<<"\n";
   trace()<< "Z : "<< neighborTable[i].z<<"\n";
   trace()<< "XDST: "<< neighborTable[i].x_dst<<"\n";
   trace()<< "YDST: "<< neighborTable[i].y_dst<<"\n";
   trace()<< "ZDST: "<< neighborTable[i].z_dst<<"\n";
   trace()<< "TS: "<< neighborTable[i].ts <<"\n";
   trace()<< "TIMESRX: "<< neighborTable[i].timesRx<<"\n";
   trace()<< "IC:  "<< neighborTable[i].ic<<"\n";


}
```

One of the results:

> ID: 30
>
> X : 26.4458
>
> Y : 38.1514
>
> Z : 0
>
> XDST: 5.43472e-323
>
> YDST: 51.8989
>
> ZDST: 50.9054
>
> TS: 1.13635e-322
>
> TIMESRX: 20615843
>
> IC:  0

I don't know if it's something when accessing the vector and I don't know how make this work. Funny fact, I've tested with less variables and it works alright. I've just seen this error when I added more variables to the struct.

Comment: Include the code that defines the struct in the question

Comment: I bet your structure has a copy ctor and you forgot to add new fields to it

Comment: Needs an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the definition of `neighborRecord`, at the very least.